# printing mails programmatically to PDF C#

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, outlook

I have a problem. I have followed different blogs here and this one http://angrez.blogspot.com/2007/06/create-pdf-in-net-using-pdfcreator.html.

I have created a program which allows me to choose which mails should be pdfed and where these should be saved. My problem is that I can not print or give the PDFCreator I use any commands which will be saved.

I have tried to follow Angrez blog, in the top link.

I need help to give the PDFCreator the following commands which it will then remember while the program runs.

Autosave option should be running.
Choose file directory.
Choose the name of the file.
print the mail with the above specified options.

If anyone can help, with some example code for the above, I would be most gracious.

Comment: "most gracious" as the hippopotamus in Fantasia?